# Lib de galeria de imagem

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Estou a procura de uma `lib` de galeria de imagem no estilo da imagem abaixo com o `page control`. Tentei criar uma usando `page view` e inserir no peço da tela com um `container`, mas não ficou bom. Tentei usar a `lib banana`, mas não ficou como esperado também.
Alguém conhece alguma `lib` de `galeria de imagem`(ou `slide de imagem`) que fique igual o da foto ou sabe como desenvolver uma?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Existem inúmeras bibliotecas que implementam essa funcionalidade. Cito aqui duas [MWPhotoBrowser](https://github.com/mwaterfall/MWPhotoBrowser) e [IDMPhotoBrowser](https://github.com/ideaismobile/IDMPhotoBrowser). Ambas funcionam com imagens locais e também remotas, fazendo o download e caching destas.

Entretanto, especialmente se você está começando, acho um exercício bem interessante você mesmo desenvolver esse componente. Sugiro utilizar um UICollectionView com orientação horizontal, onde cada imagem seria um UICollectionViewCell. Também é possível fazer usando UIScrollView, mas aí você terá que lidar com mais detalhes de implementação, uma vez que usando UICollectionView fica mais fácil implementar lazy loading (carregar somente as imagens que estão visíveis).

Nesse [link](https://adoptioncurve.net/archives/2013/04/creating-a-paged-photo-gallery-with-a-uicollectionview/) existe um tutorial de como fazer um galeria simples, usando um UICollectionView.